# This website prevent me from signing in, what should I do

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am having error when I try to sendkeys(Keys.ENTER) if I am using python to login this blibli website. But when I try to login normally from chrome browser, I can login normally without this error.

I can input the username and password with selenium python, but then it just ignores the sendkeys(Keys.Enter) command. I have tried adding the login_button.click() command, but the selenium seems to ignore the click() command too. Then, when I tried to click the login button **manually**, I got an error: **"Yah, ada eror nih. Coba lagi, ya."** Meaning: "There is an error. Please try again, ok.".

It seems like the website can detect if I am using automated software, thus prevent me from logging into the website, eventhough it is my own account.  I have attached the error screenshot. The error prevents me from clicking enter or clicking the blue login button ("Masuk").

Can anybody solve this? Thank you.

The process is complete, because I got this response:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from time import sleep
import os

CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = "C:\Development\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
URL = "https://www.blibli.com/login"
EMAIL = os.environ['EMAIL']
BLIBLI_PASSWORD = os.environ["BLIBLI_PASSWORD"]

class Blibli:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)

    def login(self):
        self.driver.get(URL)
        sleep(3)
        username = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("login__username")
        username.send_keys(EMAIL)
        # actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
        # actions.move_to_element(username).send_keys(EMAIL)
        password = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="password"]')
        password.send_keys(BLIBLI_PASSWORD, Keys.ENTER)
        login_button = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("blu-btn")
        login_button.click()

    def get_data(self):
        pass

bot = Blibli()
bot.login()
bot.get_data()
```

Comment: I think you want "password.send_keys(BLIBLI_PASSWORD + Keys.ENTER)"

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested, but still got the same error. What should I do?